# Subview in SKScene - Swift

Tags: swift, view, sprite-kit, swipe

I am making a game with SpriteKit in Swift. I have a menu divided into two equal parts, an upper and a lower. The upper part should not move, while the lower part can slide to the right or left. I tried to create a subview for this second part but I have not managed. How can I achieve this?

And I also like the second part follows the finger position when the user slides to the left or right. I think having to use UIPanGestureRecognizer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found my self a way to do it. I simply used `UIScrollView` :

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var scrollFrame: CGRect!
```

And in the `didMoveToView` function

```
scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.size.height * 0.5, self.size.width, self.size.height * 0.5))
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.size.width * 3, self.size.height * 0.5)
scrollView.bounces = false
scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.frame.width * 1, 0)
scrollView.backgroundColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
self.scene?.view?.addSubview(scrollView)
```